# rest - json response has an unknown field

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest

I setup a rest webservice with different resources.

One of them is customers which can be accessed via /api/customers

The customer class has an id, address, name and email field but for some reason the json response looks like this:

```
{
"type": "customer",
"address": {
  "city": "Kottes-Purk",
  "country": "Pakistan",
  "street": "Julius-Raab-Straße 008"
},
"email": "hana.lammert@hotmail.com",
"name": "Prof. Dr. David Mikitenko"
}
```

i dont know why there is a "type" field in the json response. Could someone explain why it's there?

The customer class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer extends Model {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Booking> bookings;

public Customer() {}

public Customer(String email, Address address, String name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.name = name;
}



public int setId() {
    return id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}


public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}


@XmlTransient
public List<Booking> getBookings() {
    return bookings;
}

public void setBookings(List<Booking> bookings) {
    this.bookings = bookings;
}


public static List<Customer> all() {
    return (List<Customer>) Database.all(Customer.class);
}


public static Customer find(int id) {
    return (Customer) Database.find(Customer.class, id);
}


public static boolean exists(int id) {
    return Database.exists(Customer.class, id);
}


public static List<Customer> where(String column, String value) {
    return (List<Customer>) Database.where(Customer.class, column, value);
}

}
```

In the CustomerResource class:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Customer> getCustomers(){
    return agencyManager.getCustomers();
}
```

What am I missing here? thank you

Model class:

```
public abstract class Model implements Serializable {


public void save() {
    EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(this);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}


public void delete() {
    EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(this) ? this : entityManager.merge(this));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have type in `Model` class?

Comment: @iNan no. The model class only has two public methods

Comment: You can log one instance of `Customer` and check if ID has been set or not.

Answer (score 1):

Id missing because of your id setter is wrong it should be

```
public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}
```

the type '"type": "customer",' might add to JSON from Model class. Have a check on Model class

Comment: you are right about the id problem. thank you. I added the model class in the first post. I don't see anything suspecious.